# How to convert an image to WORD (uint16) array?

Tags: c, image

I have some images (.bmp, .png, .jpg) in my directory. I want to convert this image to WORD array in order to display this image in LCD in 565 formats (16 bit pixel). How to convert an image to WORD array? Please help. Is is there any utility to just convert the image to binary? or Please provide some code in Windows C/CPP to convert it to binary?

Comment: You mean "How to open .bmp, .jpg, .png files in c/c++"? I would use some library for that.

Comment: Yes. I just want the binary of the pixels in it. No need of any header. Which library you used?

Comment: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?t=374650

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend a whole lot on the exact format of the input image.

Just converting "to words" isn't really expressing what you want to do, which is probably more like "convert bitmap images to an array of RGB565 pixels in row-major format".

You should look at image-processing libraries that allow you to load bitmap images, and read out the value of each pixel.

You can probably just convert directly to RGB565, shouldn't be too hard from any other bitmap format.

Note that there are both indexed and "true color" bitmap formats, and you sound like you need to handle both. If you'er lucky, the library for each format will abstract this away and have e.g. a`uint32 read_pixel_as_rgb888()`  function.

Also note that many bitmap image formats focus a lot on compression, which is why just reading in the bits of the file is not nearly enough, you need to de-compress the data according to the format. This is quite complex, which is why pre-written libraries are the only sane choice.

For PNG, look at [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html), for JPEG look for [libjpeg](http://www.ijg.org/). On second thought, these libraries might be a bit too low-level, and maybe you should look at something like [SDL_Image](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use CImg to open image files - http://cimg.sourceforge.net/